# prepareForSegue style action for unwind?

Tags: ios

I have an app that has a visible blue navbar all the way through except on profiles which have a clear navbar like shown in this screenshot:

[image]

When i push the profile controller it works great by hiding the navbar and displays like above but if I click the back button it reverses to the previous viewcontroller where I call to display the navbar again and then there is a short delay before it updates the navbar on the unwound viewcontroller which looks weird.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a better way around this. I was thinking there might be a way to complete the unhide of the navbar before the transition between viewcontrollers, sort of like a prepareForSegue but for an unwind?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Code please, without code we can't suggest any solution

Answer (score 1):

Show/hide navbar using viewWillAppear: and viewWillDisappear: methods